# Does L'Hospital's rule still hold when derivatives are w.r.t different variables?

Tags: analysis

This question is provoked by an (in fact standard) [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269575/prob-11-chap-5-in-baby-rudin-if-f-is-defined-in-a-neighborhood-of-x-and) to one of Baby Rudin’s exercises.

> Suppose $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x$, and suppose $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ >exists. Show that $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2} = >f^{\prime\prime}(x).$$
> *Hint:* Use Theorem 5.13. [i.e. L'Hospital's rule]

What confuses me is the first step, using L'Hospital's rule:

> \begin{align}
> \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) -2f(x) }{h^2} 
> &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^\prime(x+h) - f^\prime(x-h)}{2h} \\
> & \ \ \  \mbox{ [ using L'Hospital's rule, } \\
> & \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{ because $f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x) \to 0$ and $h \to 0$ } \\
> & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{ as $h \to 0$ ]} \\
> &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f^\prime(x+h) - f^\prime(x) + f^\prime(x) - f^\prime(x-h) }{2h} 
> \end{align}

etc. But I believe the rule is about equating $\tfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $\tfrac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)}$, i.e. ratio of functions resp. derivatives w.r.t the same variable, but were $g(x)=h^2$, we would have $g^\prime(x)=0$ for all $x \in \rm{Dom} \it f$, thus destroying the ratio. So are we permitted to differentiate w.r.t $x$ in the numerator and w.r.t $h$ in the denominator?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand.  In the usual presentation, there's only $x$.  If you had, e.g., $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {f(x)}{h^2}$, that would just be $\frac 1{h^2}\times \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$.  In the second presentation, there is only $h$.

Comment: @lulu That’s exactly what’s giving me trouble, apparently in the second presentation we are taking an ‘alien’ derivative in the denominator: $(h^2)^\prime=2h$.

Comment: You are differentitating with respect to $h$ in both numerator and denominator.  $x$ is fixed throughout.  I agree that writing $f'$ is a bit confusing since normally that would mean $\frac d{dx}f$.  But note the sign change.  $\frac d{dx}f(x-h)$ would just be $f'(x-h)$ while $\frac d{dh} f(x-h)=-f'(x-h)$, where of course I am perpetuating the abuse of notation, in both instances, $f'$ refers to the appropriate derivative.

Comment: @lulu But if we are diffentiating uniformly, i.e. with respect to $h$, will the resulting $f^\prime(x+h)$ (i.e. with notation abuse) be the same? The proof is completed by evoking the definition of $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ as $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f^\prime(x+h) - f^\prime(x) }{h} $ etc., where  $f^\prime(x+h)$ resumes its common denotation.

Comment: I suggest ditching that notation, it causes nothing but confusion.  Just use $\frac d{dh}$, or even better $\frac {\partial}{\partial h}$ and so on.  But, sure.  Those functions are the same, as functions.  Consider $f(x)=x^2$ as an example.  Then $F(x,h)=f(x+h)=x^2+2hx+h^2$ and so$\frac {\partial}{\partial h}F(x,h)=2h+2x$ which is also $\frac {\partial}{\partial x}F(x,h)$.  I'm sure this equality is why the author is comfortable with the notation, but I still think it is confusing.  And, of course, that equality requires proof...which I assume he supplies?

Comment: To be sure, you need only remark that nothing is changed under a transposition under $x,h$ but it still merits being pointed out.

Comment: @lulu No, no proof is given for the «transposition invariance» in the solution, but I find it surprisingly simple, let$u=x+h,\; g(x, h)=f(u),\; $then$\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial h}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, anyway the invariance may as well be explained by symmetry.

Comment: @lulu What I overlooked seems to be the fact that $x$ and $h$ are parameters with respect to each other, hence $\frac{\partial g}{\partial h}$ is itself a function about $x$ and  vice versa, its value therefore still depending on the latter.

Comment: I agree,  it's not difficult.  But  I'd say the discussion the author provides is at least a little confusing.